# Rest Sharp Patch Request

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm very new still to Rest Sharp and Postman but I'm trying to make a "Update" to an existing user. Here is my code but I know its wrong. Does anyone have samples on how to perform a "replace" operation in Rest Sharp?

```
string url = _EndPoint + "?_action = patch & _queryId =for-userName & uid =" + obj.userName.ToString();
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            string username = "openidm-admin";
            string password = "openidm-admin";
            string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            string Update = BuildUpdate();

            //if (Update != null)
            //{
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            //request.AddParameter("application/json", "[\n  {\n    \"operation\": \"replace\",\n    \"field\": \"/userName\",\n    \"value\": \"testuser4@aha.org\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"operation\": \"replace\",\n    \"field\": \"/mail\",\n    \"value\": \"testuser4@aha.org\"\n  }\n]", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            request.AddBody({ "operation": "replace", "field": "/userName", "value": "testuser4@aha.org"}, { "operation": "replace",  "field": "/mail", "value": "testuser4@aha.org"});
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Postman says it should be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "replace",
    "field": "/userName",
    "value": "testuser4@aha.org"
  },
  {
    "operation": "replace",
    "field": "/mail",
    "value": "testuser4@aha.org"
  }
]
```

I would prefer to write it that way but I have no idea how. The other code suggested I make a string. I can write it out via string but Id prefer to write it out in the body if I can or possible. Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

Here is my class:

```
public class IdentityDetails
    {
        //public const string type = "user";
        //public const string realm = "dc=aha,dc=org";        
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string mail { get; set; }
        public string givenName { get; set; }
        public string sn { get; set; }
        public string accountStatus { get; set; }
        public string avectraId { get; set; }
        public string AHApw { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string ahaBirthYear { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string ahaGender { get; set; }
        public string ahaJobTitle { get; set; }
        public string ahaLeadScore { get; set; }
        public string stateProvince { get; set; }
        public string orgId { get; set; }
        public string[] ahaMemberGroup { get; set; }
        public string[] ahaMemberType { get; set; }
        public string regMethod { get; set; }
        //public string[] ahaDrupalPermission { get; set; }
    }
```

I think what I need to do though as well will be pass in the current field and value, and pass in the new value for the field. I'm just looking for a sample code though of someone else performing a update request using Restsharp. I could write it all out in a string but I'm hoping for a easier way then using a string and passing as a parameter.

**Edit**

I'm currently trying to do it by building a string to pass in as the parameter. I know there has to be a better way. Here is my current progress on building a string;

Postman String:

```
request.AddParameter("application/javascript", "[\n  {\n    \"operation\": \"replace\",\n    \"field\": \"/userName\",\n    \"value\": \"testuser4@aha.org\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"operation\": \"replace\",\n    \"field\": \"/mail\",\n    \"value\": \"testuser4@aha.org\"\n  }\n]", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

My string builder function in progress:

```
private string BuildUpdate(string field, string newvalue, string oldvalue)
        {
            try
            {
                string Update = string.Empty;
                string UpdateOperation = '"' + "operation" + '"' + ": " + '"' + "replace\"" + ",\n" + '"';
                string Updatefield = "field" + '"' + ": \"";
                string UpdateNewValue = "/" + newvalue + '"' + ",\n";
                string 

                // "[\n  {\n    \"operation\": \"replace\",\n\"
                // field\": \"
                // /userName\",\n    
                // \"value\": \"testuser4@aha.org\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"operation\": \"replace\",\n    \"field\": \"/mail\",\n    \"value\": \"testuser4@aha.org\"\n  }\n]"

                return Update;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Anyone have a better way to do this?

Comment: I believe you can create a class and use AddBody to serialize the particular object of that class, which should simplify your problem.

Comment: Your body should be an array.  `request.AddBody(new [] { .... })`

Comment: Do you have a code snippet you can share showing you update and replace a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my problem. I'm not sure if I have this in the right order but I got the string formatted correctly. I hope this helps someone else as well.

Here is my base function for performing my REST update request using Restsharp:

```
public string UpdateRequest(string uid, string field, string newvalue, string oldvalue)
        {
            try
            { 
                string url = _EndPoint + "?_action = patch & _queryId =for-userName & uid =" + uid;
                var client = new RestClient(url);
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                string username = "openidm-admin";
                string password = "openidm-admin";
                string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
                string Update = BuildUpdate(field, newvalue, oldvalue);

                if (Update != null)
                {
                    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
                    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                    request.AddParameter("application/json", Update, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

                    return response.Content.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Error
                    return "Error";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I'm calling my BuildUpdate function to return my Json string that I will use to pass in as my parameter. Here is my function to build the update string. I broke it up into two parts and converted each part into a json string format. Then I combine them into a single string:

```
private string BuildUpdate(string field, string newvalue, string oldvalue)
        {
            try
            {
                //Parameter String
                string Update = string.Empty;

                //New Value
                var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                dict1.Add("operation", "replace");
                dict1.Add("field", field);
                dict1.Add("value", newvalue);
                string json1 = Regex.Unescape(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict1, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));

                //Current Value
                var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                dict2.Add("operation", "replace");
                dict2.Add("field", field);
                dict2.Add("value", oldvalue);
                string json2 = Regex.Unescape(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict2, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));

                Update = json1 + ",\n " + json2;

                return Update;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Here is my output string I will pass in as my parameter:

```
"{\r\n  \"operation\": \"replace\",\r\n  \"field\": \"userName\",\r\n  \"value\": \"testuser999@aha.org\"\r\n},\n {\r\n  \"operation\": \"replace\",\r\n  \"field\": \"userName\",\r\n  \"value\": \"testuser4@aha.org\"\r\n}"
```

Update:
I just wanted to share my working code sample with everyone.

Function 1:

```
public string UpdateRequest(string uid, string field, string value)
        {
            try
            { 
                string url = _EndPoint + "?_action=patch&_queryId=for-userName&uid=" + uid;
                var client = new RestClient(url);
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                string username = "openidm-admin";
                string password = "openidm-admin";
                string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
                string Update = BuildUpdate(field, value);

                if (Update != null)
                {
                    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
                    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                    request.AddParameter("application/json", Update, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

                    return response.Content.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Error
                    return "Error";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Here is the string building function to build your Json string for the request:

```
private string BuildUpdate(string field, string value)
        {
            try
            {
                //Parameter String
                string json = string.Empty;

                //Value
                var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                dict.Add("operation", "replace");
                dict.Add("field", field);
                dict.Add("value", value);
                json = "[\n" + Regex.Unescape(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)) + "\n]";

                return json;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure why I have to add "[\n" or "\n]" but I assume its wrapping it for some reason. Anyway, I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I think I might be wrong a little on my answer. I might only need the dict1 variable. The documentation I was given has a confusing sample. So for anyone else just remove + ",\n " + json2 from the output string and it should work for you I think. Line will look like this: Update = json1;